# Extraer valor de una variable que esta adentro de un action listener en java

Tags: java, java-swing

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas, estoy encaminando un proyecto de secundaria con java, mysql, y swing. El caso es que necesito hacer un get de el valor de una variable que esta adentro un actionlistener, pero no se como. Adjunto una imagen descriptiva

La variable azul es a la que quiero darle el valor de la variable roja, para usarla en otra función

Agradeceria si me responden

Saludos

Comment: La imagen no se muestra u olvidaste enlazarla

Comment: Ya la envio, crei que la había adjuntado

Comment: Ahora si ya se encuentra adjunta en la publicación

Comment: Por favor nada de fotos , comparte el código en formato texto

Answer (score 0):

La manera de acceder a dicha variable es declararla como atributo de la clase y luego acceder (dentro del ActionListener) a dicha variable. Es decir:

Si tu clase se llama DtnEscribirMail entonces:

```
public class DtnEscribirMail ... {

    private String correo = "";

    .
    .
    .
    DtnEscribirMail.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            correo = .....
            .....
            .....
        }
    } 
    );
}
```

**Se trata de un problema del scope(ámbito) de la variable**. Una variable **definida dentro del ActionListener** tiene un **scope reducido** a este mismo ActionListener y por lo tanto solo se puede acceder a esta desde dentro de este, mientras que una variable **definida fuera de este ActionListener** tiene un **scope más amplio** y puede ser accedida desde otros métodos.

Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

```
//arriba en los atributos declaras una variable tipo String
  private String correoActual
//en el constructor la inicializas correoActual="";
 //si es valido el correo entonces

  correoActual=correo;
}
/*
 *Variables
 Variable local: es aquella que sólo es utilizable dentro del código
 de la función.

 Variable global: es aquella cuyo ámbito es todo el programa, incluso 
 dentro de una función.

 En tu código tenes a correoActual como una variable local.
```

Estas, son las que tenes dentro de los métodos, cuando el método termina
 Java las desecha.
     En cambio si usas la variable como global,
 estas perduran mientras esté la instancia abierta.

```
Donde van las variables globales:

public class nombreDeLaClase {
//Varibles globales
   //Atributos de instancia
     private String correoActual;
   //Atributos de clase
     private static final int NOMBRE_DE_VARIABLE_FIJA = entero;
  //entero porque es int, pero puede ser de otro tipo de dato
}
*/
```